# RecyclerView help get data

Tags: android-recyclerview

I already get the position of the recyclerview item plus I also want to get the data that is in that list as the title that was stored in the position

Use this snippet to get a position it works

```
new RecyclerItemClickListener(recyclerView.getContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        // TODO Handle item click
        Log.i("DIGI-TOUCH", String.valueOf(itemView.getId()));
    }
})
);
```

and class

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
    View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved, use position  to traverse the array that comes the data by importing this array into a class